# Package com.facebook.android does not exist

Tags: android

I am new to Android development and I have been given to revive an old project and fix some bugs. When I open the project in Android Studio I get errors related to facebook package does not exist. The project structure is given below:

[image]

The build.gradle contains the following code:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

}
```

The errors I receive are shown below:

[image]

What can I do to resolve the issue?

**UPDATE: Complete Build.gradle file:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your libraries to Android Studio.

Open the libs folder and right click the facebook library and then select "Add as library". Then perhaps rebuild the project.

Comment: There is no facebook library inside the libs folder. There is no .jar file for facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Add the Maven Central Repository to your project’s build.gradle:

```
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
```

And now add the Facebook SDK to your app in the app’s build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
        compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.23.1'
    }
```

Documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android).

**Edit:** Option 2 (Local)

Download the Facebook SDK form [here](https://developers.facebook.com/resources/facebook-android-sdk-current.zip).

Create a folder “libs” in your project root.

Copy the content of the Facebook SDK to the “libs” folder.

Open settings.gradle and add the library to your app:

```
include ':app'
include ':libs:facebook-android-sdk-3.23.1'
```

Now add it in the build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
            compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
            compile project(':libs:facebook-android-sdk-3.23.1')
        }
```

Comment: It says unable to find com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.23.1

Comment: @john Please post all your build.gradle files.

Comment: I just posted the complete build.gradle file in the original question.

Comment: @john Maybe you use offline gradle? Go to File -> Settings -> Gradle -> Offline Work (try to enable and disable it)

Comment: I just did that but that did not made a difference.